# How to find the members of a dynamically loaded com object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, registry, ole

I am trying to use an OLE COM object that I don't have any documentation for. I load the com object dynamically by:

```
dynamic comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("The Program ID"));
```

The Program ID in the registry points to some exe (or at least that is what I think, I cannot tell for sure. Is there a way to know where exactly does it point to). I tried loading the exe in an OLE COM viewer, but I was not able to get any useful information out of it. For example, I was not able to find a method that I knew for sure was there. Actually, after loading the comObject I am able to invoke this method without any problems, but I would like to know if there is a way that I can list/view all the members of this COM object.

Comment: Do you have the .tlb file? Did you try loading that in the OLE/COM viewer?

Comment: I don't have the tlb. I tried loading the .exe to the OLE COM viewer that comes with Visual Studio, but that didn't get out any useful information.

Comment: If the type information isn't merged into the COM server, it has to be somewhere.

Comment: @enmtm - OOC, Is this a commonly available object (ie: public somewhere)?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all of the methods through the IDispatch interface, if it supports it.

[Here is an MSDN article that uses IDispatch to get member info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347981.aspx)

Comment: That is similar to @L.B's code. Did not work for me. Not sure if the COM implements IDispatch.

Comment: Have you tried adding the object to a .NET project?  If the typelib is embedded or it implements IDispatch, it will read it out and you should be able to see the interfaces through Intellisense.  If Visual Studio can't resolve the type interface, and you don't have the typelib, then I don't know how else you'll be able to derive the interface without decompiling the library.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I wasn't able to add a reference to it in Visual Studio. It cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Given `ProgID` you can use API functions and/or look up registry (such as under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key) for COM server `CLSID` and binary that hosts the class, including full path to executable.

If you have a reference to a type library there, you can also load it and check implemented interfaced and interface information. You can also possibly obtain this information from an instance of COM object too, provided that it implements interfaces like `IDispatch`, `IDispatchEx`, `IProvideClassInfo`.

Comment: Well, I found that it points to where I thought it did. So, still can't get any useful information out of it. I don't know for sure if it implements IDispatch, I tried it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I copied this source. I beg a pardon from the author.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [
       ComImport,
       Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
       InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)
    ]
    public interface IDispatch
    {
        void Reserved();
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetTypeInfo(uint nInfo, int lcid,
           [MarshalAs(
              UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler,
              MarshalTypeRef = typeof(TypeToTypeInfoMarshaler))]
           out System.Type typeInfo);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type t1 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime");
            Object o1 = Activator.CreateInstance(t1);

            IDispatch disp2 = o1 as IDispatch;
            if (disp2 != null)
            {
                Type t3;
                disp2.GetTypeInfo(0, 0, out t3);

                MemberInfo[] mlist3 = t3.GetMembers();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the  CustomMarshalers.dll in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\

Comment: I think here is the source [link](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-interop/8249/Introspecting-COM-Object-in-C)

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work for me. t3 always returns as null from disp2.GetTypeInfo(0, 0, out t3);

Comment: Maybe the COM doesn't implement the IDispatch interface. I don't know for sure. Is there is a way I can check that?